# Finally found a Jquery scroll to div(!)... now to add easing..?

Tags: jquery

http://subzerostudio.com/temp/verticalscroller/scroller/scroller.html

Here's the fullscreen vertical scrolling site.. I've only tested it in FF so could well be buggy..

Assuming it actually works, I now want to add easing and speed, I've tried this:

```
    $('html,body').animate({
        duration: 6000,
        easing: 'easeOutElastic',
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top}
        );
```

but the duration has no effect and easing doesn't seem to be working either.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation syntax is incorrect.

```
$('html body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
}, 6000, 'easeOutElastic');
```

As you have it, you're telling jQuery to animate the `duration` and `easing` properties of the body, which don't exist.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: use the selector 'html,body' not 'html body' if it should work in IE and FF, the space-one only works in webkit-browsers (like GC), the comma-one in all (the ones I've tried).